# How to Install WP to Subdomain but Serve on Subdirectory?

Tags: directory, subdomains, nginx

I want to install Wordpress to a subdomain (`sub.example.com`) but want to serve it on the subfolder (`example.com/sub`).

I want to do this because the root domain (`example.com`) is a different web app so installing WP to subdomain is better to manage.

I read several articles about proxy / Nginx etc. but want to know how to organize this structure from the **beginning**. I mean if there is anything I should be careful about for this structure because I know the WP installation will be served on different URL.

---

## Install: sub.example.com | REDIRECTION | Serve: example.com/sub

Comment: Why not just install it in the sub directory?

Comment: Because I want to use different servers for app and Wordpress for security reasons.

Comment: @herci, you should tag the person(s) you're responding to so that he/she/they could be notified of your replies. Anyway, are you saying that `example.com` and `sub.example.com` are handled by different servers - e.g. Nginx for the former and Apache for the latter? Are you looking for something like [this](https://en.support.wordpress.com/domains/map-subdomain/#pointing-your-subdomain-to-an-external-site)?..